A Perfect Set Containing Only Rational Numbers
Let $S$ be a set of arbitrarily dense rational numbers—that is, $S$ contains the limit points of all its rational numbers, as for any epsilon neighborhood around a point $r_n$ within $S$ an infinite number of rational numbers can be found within $(r_n-\epsilon, r_n+\epsilon)$. Now, construct the set $I$ composed of a union of epsilon neighborhoods around each irrational number, and form the set $P$ as the intersection of $S$ and the complement of $I$ (i.e. a set containing all real numbers except those within the open intervals around each irrational number)—then, the set $P$ contains no isolated points and also contains no limit points (any irrational number that could have been a limit point of a sequence of rationals in S has been expunged from the set, at least I think), thus making it perfect.
But this is obviously wrong. All perfect sets are uncountable, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, thus as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ P is uncountable and cannot be perfect.
Where is the flaw in the construction of my "perfect" rational set?

Maybe I am misunderstanding the construction, but isn't the complement of I just the empty set?

...because between any two rational numbers there's an infinite number of irrationals-yep, that explains it, since the set P would then be empty as well. Thanks!

@SoumikMukherjee - The complement of $I$ need not be empty. It could even been countably infinite. For example, for each irrational $r$, you could choose $\epsilon_r$ to be the distance to the nearest integer. Thus no integers would occur in any of the $\epsilon$-neighborhoods, and the complement of $I$ would be $\Bbb Z$.

But from that example, you can see that the claim $P$ has no isolated points is false. As is the claim it contains no limit points. (Yes, it contains no irrational limit points, but there is no reason it cannot have rational limit points. For example, as above, but $\epsilon_r$ is chosen $\le$ the distance from $r$ to any of the points ${1/z : z\in\Bbb Z, z \ne 0}$. $0 \in P$ and is a limit point of $P$.)

@PaulSinclair I assumed the epsilon was fixed, I didn't think this way, thank you
